# Is there any better way to express this "I had to mouth these words"?

Tags: synonyms, non-native-english

Please watch [this video from 2:46](https://youtu.be/F-wLKzjbRf4).

> I had to mouth these words also in the middle of the song. And, I sat up two nights. When I went on the sets, I had to do it between 10 to 20 elephants. They were all adorned and beautiful and all...

I have a feeling that the above is not proper English. However, in my head, I am also not finding any proper alternative.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with these sentences and also the correct native English?

EDIT: The following is my proposal:

> *I also had to utter these words in the song. I was awake for two nights (!!). In the set, I had to do it with 10 to 20 elephants. They were all beautifully ornamented, all...*

Comment: “To mouth” is certainly English: Hamlet (Act 3 Scene 2) “Speak the speech, I pray you, as I pronounced it to
you, trippingly on the tongue: but if you mouth it,
as many of your players do, I had as lief the
town-crier spoke my lines”

Comment: What do you think is wrong? It sounds pretty good to me.

Comment: “Lip-sync” is the alternative.

Comment: @Xanne, the entire quote is non-standard English.

Comment: According to the title, the question is only about the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

To mouth the words of a song usually means you cannot actually sing the song. Or you do not know the words and so just mouth along to the end. In this case it may mean that the words could not be heard in the show no matter how well you could sing them. No microphone near the elephants. As djs makes cleariIt is perfectly good English.